# Using MySQL subQuery to get individual totals

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get my MySQL table to return rows for total amount by each member in a given year. Below is the SQL query I wrote

```
SELECT First_name, last_name, (SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM contributions
WHERE contributions.memberid = members.memberid AND year = '2013') AS amount  FROM members
```

and I get this error

MySQL Error#: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

I am using MySQL 5.5.24

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a column named `year` or are you storing datetime?

Comment: I have a column named year

Comment: Is that the full query that you are using? I am not getting an error in the demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d346/2

Comment: It is throwing errors on Dreamweaver

Comment: Did you try the query in my answer to see if that throws any error?

Comment: I tried it, they didnt throw any error. but error persists in dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can possibly see is that you have the year in single quotes, but I am not reproducing the error in [this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d346/2).

You can also write the query using a subquery and a JOIN:

```
select m.first_name,
  m.last_name,
  c.amount
from members m
inner join
(
  select sum(amount) Amount, memberid
  from contributions
  where year = 2013
  group by memberid
) c
  on m.memberid = c.memberid
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d346/2)

If you are not storing `year` in a separate column and you have a datetime column, then you will need to use the `year()` function:

```
select m.first_name,
  m.last_name,
  c.amount
from members m
inner join
(
  select sum(amount) Amount, memberid
  from contributions
  where year(yourDate) = 2013
  group by memberid
) c
  on m.memberid = c.memberid
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe changing you code this way:

```
SELECT First_name, 
last_name, 
(SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM contributions 
WHERE contributions.memberid = members.memberid 
 AND contributions.year = '2013') AS amount 
FROM members
```

I only change this line,

```
AND contributions.year = '2013'
```

because maybe is ambigued in your query(exist in both tables)

Saludos )

Comment: Thanks guys, turns out my query was ok. Maybe a bug in my Dreamweaver, so I had to hard code it. My problem is solved.